# Can't add markers on real time on Google maps API for Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I know how to add markers before the program runs, but I do not know how to let the user insert his own markers while the program is already running, and how to keep it stored.

Do you have an idea if gmaps API for Android has this functionality and if it really works?

I'm walking in circles and I can't find it anyway, I would really appreciate if you could help me with it.

Here is my code with a static marker in Rio:

```
package com.example.dborahramos.myapplication;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng rio = new LatLng(-22.9035,-43.2096);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(rio).title("Rio"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(rio));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share what have you tried so far ?

Comment: You should refresh the map everytime you insert a new marker.

Comment: Pirate X, code now posted.

Answer (score 0):

First create Marker List.

```
List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<Marker>();
```

To get a new mark from the user and save it in DB, you could use OnMapClickListener, you get the location from the map where the user clicked.

```
GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener onMapClickListener = new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(final LatLng location){
                //Save new marker in DB with locations.
                ServerRequest.SaveMarker(location,title)....
                 Callback(){ //Callback
                  clearMarkers(); //Clear previus markers to not overCreate
                  addMarkers(); //Get new Markers from DB and add to the map
                 }
            }
        };
        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(onMapClickListener);
```

Then when you want to print new markers from DB, first you have to get markers and save it to a List. If you have loaded markers before, remember to remove all exists markers on the map first.

```
private void clearMarkers(){
for(int i = 0; i < markers.size(); i++)
{
  markers.get(i).remove();
}
}

private void addMarkers(){
List<MyLocations> list = ServerRequest.ReturnMarkers....
for(MyLocations ml : list)
{
  markers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(ml.getLat(), ml.getLng()).title(ml.getTitle())));
}
}
```

Some code
Add new marker whenever you want

```
markers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lng)).title("Title")));
```

Delete marker

```
markers.get(index).remove();
```